# Validation error messages not show Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

I created custom rules in app/config/validation but the error messages not show.

Controller code:

```
// Validasi Form Data
$this->valid    = \Config\Services::validation();
$this->valid->setRuleGroup('produk');
$this->data = $this->request->getPost("formData");
if (!$this->valid->run($this->data)) {
    return $this->response->setStatusCode(500)->setJSON($this->valid->getError());
}
```

Validation Code:

```
public $produk = [
'nama_produk'     => [
    'label'     =>  'Nama Produk',
    'rules'     =>  'required|alpha_numeric_space|min_length[3]',
    'errors'    =>  [
        'required'              =>  '{field} harus diisi.',
        'alpha_numeric_space'   =>  'Hanya boleh mengisi huruf, angka atau spasi pada kolom {field}.',
        'min_length'            =>  'Nama produk yang diinput setidaknya harus {param} karakter.'
    ],
],
'harga_produk'     => [
    'label'     =>  'Harga Produk',
    'rules'     =>  'required|numeric|min_length[3]',
    'errors'    =>  [
        'required'      =>  '{field} harus diisi.',
        'numeric'       =>  'Hanya boleh mengisi dengan angka pada kolom {field}.',
        'min_length'    =>  'Harga produk yang diinput setidaknya harus {param} karakter.'
    ]
]
```

No error message :
[Error messages not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3ErW.png)

But if the harga_produk array commented, the error message show.

```
public $produk = [
'nama_produk'     => [
    'label'     =>  'Nama Produk',
    'rules'     =>  'required|alpha_numeric_space|min_length[3]',
    'errors'    =>  [
        'required'              =>  '{field} harus diisi.',
        'alpha_numeric_space'   =>  'Hanya boleh mengisi huruf, angka atau spasi pada kolom {field}.',
        'min_length'            =>  'Nama produk yang diinput setidaknya harus {param} karakter.'
    ],
],
/* 'harga_produk'     => [
    'label'     =>  'Harga Produk',
    'rules'     =>  'required|numeric|min_length[3]',
    'errors'    =>  [
        'required'      =>  '{field} harus diisi.',
        'numeric'       =>  'Hanya boleh mengisi dengan angka pada kolom {field}.',
        'min_length'    =>  'Harga produk yang diinput setidaknya harus {param} karakter.'
    ]
], */
```

Error Messages:
[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltnP0.png)

i use ajax to send formData to controller and sweetalert to display the notification, code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: `../admin/produk/savedata`,
            method: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success: () => {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Data produk berhasil diinput.',
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    timer: 2500
                });
            },
            error: (msg) => {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: msg.responseText,
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    timer: 2500
                });
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: How are you displaying the errors?  I think we need to see [the view](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#creating-the-views) and [view config](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#configuration)? You are returning JSON, so maybe there is some Javascript involved, can yo show us that? Have you checked in your browser's devtools, is the right response being returned to the browser?

Comment: in devtools in the network response section it says this request has no response available and http status 500 because I set $this->response->setStatusCode(500) if there is an error

Comment: OK, that sounds like a *real* 500 error, maybe? Anything in your CI logs, or web server/PHP logs?  I would suggest don't use 500 as your response code, for exactly this reason - you can't tell now if it is validation error, or if you have a PHP error and that is generating a *real* 500/server error.  I think 422 is more commonly used for validation errors - 4** means client error, and that is what a validation error signals.